# Solving recursive definition while factorials are involved

Tags: recurrence-relations, factorial

I've recently started studying recursive definitions of sequences and have encountered a recurrence formula which seems to include a factorial. Until now I have not seen any like this.

$$t_n = 5  \,\frac{(n + 1)!}{4^n} ,\quad n ≥ 1.$$

If I was to take a look at this segment (n + 1)! and replace n with position 1 would the factorial simply be 2! which I can then input back into the recurrence formula like :

$$t_n = 5\, \frac{2!}{4^n} ,\quad n ≥ 1.$$

Apologies for any incorrect terminology.

Comment: $5 (n+1)!/4^n = 5\; 2!/4^n$ only when $n = 1$, not for any other $n$.

Comment: And that is not a recursive definition of $t_n$.

Answer (score 1):

$$T_n=5 \frac{(n+1)!}{4^n}~~~~(1)$$ will follow the recurrence relation given by
$$T_{n}=\frac{1}{4}(n+1)T_{n-1}~~~~(2)$$

EDIT for OP:

Now in order to get (1) from (2) one can do multiplicative telescoping or
divide (2) by $(n+1)!$ to get
$$\frac{T_n}{(n+1)!}=\frac{1}{4}\frac{(n+1)T_{n-1}}{(n+1)!}=\frac{1}{4}\frac{T_{n-1}}{n}~~~(3)$$
Next, define $\frac{T_{n-1}}{n!}=V_{n-1}$
to get $$V_{n}=\frac{1}{4} V_{n-1} \implies V_n=(\frac{1}{4})^n C \implies \frac{T_n}{(n+1)!}=\frac{C}{4^n},$$
giving back (1), where the constant $C=5$.

Comment: Oh! yes vey much, thanks.

Comment: That's good and all about the Recurrence relation but I was more curious to know if the factorial played any major part in discerning the solution and an explanation about what the factorial changes in solving the recurrence formula.

Comment: @LiamSaxon The fundamental thing to notice is that each piece of this is multiplicative: increasing $n$ by $1$ multiplies the numerator by $n+2$ and multiplies the denominator by $4$.  That's what tells you that the recurrence relation should be of the form $T_n=f(n)T_{n-1}$.

Comment: @Liam Saxon You may see my edit now.